# Where to buy a USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 or Gen 2 cable capable of carrying 3 Amps?

Tags: usb, cable

First as a remainder, this norm is only available with a USB type C connector. And in reality, it’s rather not a unique standard but 3:

- USB 3.2 Gen 1 at 5 Gbps (SuperSpeed USB which means same characteristics as ᴜꜱʙ 3.1)
- USB 3.2 Gen 2 at 10 Gbps (SuperSpeed USB 10 Gbps)
- USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 at 20 Gbps (SuperSpeed USB 20 Gbps).

Of course, the current standard rules out cables with USB type A connectors (the one everyone uses).
I have the hardware which can use such cable, but with standard subtle differences, I wasn’t able to find the cable I’m wanting ... Or one at least 1.5 meter long.

Comment: I just found [this](https://www.amazon.fr/Lemorele-Soutien-Thunderbolt-Nintendo-ChromeBook/dp/B07RQQDT8R/ref=asc_df_B07RQQDT8R/?tag=googshopfr-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=356485628603&hvpos=1o6&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13677188825149780415&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9055547&hvtargid=pla-781055759680&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=71692063909&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=356485628603&hvpos=1o6&hvnetw=g&hvrand=13677188825149780415&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9055547&hvtargid=pla-781055759680). but it’s not enough long for going from the ᴘᴄ to the desk.